# ASP.NET core with Entity Framework many-to-many not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two models, and a model to connect the two.

`Organization` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Verbonding.Models
{
    public class Organization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OrganizationApplicationUser> OrganizationApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public Organization()
        {
            IsActive = true;
            IsBlocked = false;
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public ApplicationUser AddUser(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            OrganizationApplicationUser ou = new OrganizationApplicationUser { ApplicationUser = user, Organization = this };

            OrganizationApplicationUsers.Add(ou);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` model:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace Verbonding.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<OrganizationApplicationUser> OrganizationApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser():base()
        {
            IsActive = true;
            IsBlocked = false;
            DateJoined = DateTime.Now;
            DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public IQueryable<Organization> GetOrganizations()
        {
            return OrganizationApplicationUsers.Select(x => x.Organization);
;       }
    }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Verbonding.Models;

namespace Verbonding.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<OrganizationApplicationUser>().HasKey(x => new { x.OrganizationId, x.ApplicationUserId });
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrganizationApplicationUser> OrganizationApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After some research I also added this code to the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
builder.Entity<OrganizationApplicationUser>()
    .HasOne(ou => ou.Organization)
    .WithMany(o => o.OrganizationApplicationUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(ou => ou.Organization);

builder.Entity<OrganizationApplicationUser>()
    .HasOne(ou => ou.ApplicationUser)
    .WithMany(u => u.OrganizationApplicationUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(ou => ou.ApplicationUserId);
```

Using the debugger I found out that `OrganizationApplicationUsers`remains `null`.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Your naming is a bit confusing. Do you mean `Organization.OrganizationApplicationUsers` or `ApplicationDbContext.OrganizationApplicationUsers` remains null?

Comment: *When* does it remain `null`? If you expect it to lazy load -- that's not (yet) supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have what is called a many to many relationship between entities, you need to link the `ApplicationUser` to the `Organization` directly (under the hood, entity framework is gonna create the table between, but your class won't know about it.

Other than that, in the `ApplicationUser`, it should be an IColletion and not an `IQueryable`.